# Put all indexs of array in a comma separated string

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have an array that looks like this:

```
array('first' => 'value1', 'second' => 'value2', ...);
```

How can I get all the keys and put them in a comma separated string?

At the very end I need something like this, to do a query:

```
values IN ('first','second',...)
```

Thanks

Comment: array_keys() would do that for you.

Comment: @Jack not quite. That will give them an array of the keys. They will then have to `implode()` that.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition). It deals with a similar problem.

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle op already has `implode` tag on the question, so my comment should give enough information.

Comment: BTW, instead of injecting that string directly, you really should make sure that you are using PDO prepared statements for this. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 17, accepted):

should be enough:

```
echo "'".implode("','", array_keys($array))."'";
```

Comment: Comment deleted because I was being dumb.

Comment: nope, explode = string to array; implode = array to string

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle hapens to the best of us :D

Answer (score 2):

`array_keys` will grab all the keys, `implode` will combine them into a string.

```
implode("','", array_keys($array));
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is to use `array_keys()` to get the array indices.

However, since you're using this in SQL, it's important to also properly escape the values:

```
$db = new PDO( ... );
$sql .= "value IN (" . 
        join(', ', array_map(array($db, 'quote'), array_keys($arr))) . ")";
```

Or, when you prefer using prepared statements:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('... WHERE value IN (' . 
    join(',', array_fill(0, count($arr), '?')) . ')');
$stmt->execute(array_keys($arr));
```

Comment: IMHO it would be much better to use `VALUE IN (?)` and `->execute(array(implode("','",array_keys($array))`

Comment: @Rufinus I wouldn't say *much* better, but that's a good alternative :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = '';
$keys = array_keys($array);

foreach($keys as $key) { 
$result .= $key.',';
}

$result = rtrim($result, ',');
```

Comment: this will lead to 
`first, second` not to `'first','second'`

Answer (score -1):

Have a at [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php). It seems like the thing you need. To combine the keys, use implode as suggested by many other users:

```
implode("','", array_keys($array));
```